# Ant: Problem: failed to create task or type propertyregex

Tags: ant

I'm using Ant 1.8.1.  I have downloaded ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar and placed it in my $ANT_HOME/lib directory.  However, when I include this in my build.xml file ...

```
<propertyregex property="selenium.email.success.subject"
          input="package.ABC.name"
          regexp="(.*)__ENV__(.*)"
          replace="\1${buildtarget}\2"
          override="true"
          casesensitive="false" />
```

I get the error "Problem: failed to create task or type propertyregex.  Cause: The name is undefined." upon running my Ant build file.  What else do I need to do to get this task recognized?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `propertyregex` ant task is part of [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/), and not included by default in any [apache-ant](http://ant.apache.org/) installation.

You have to properly install `ant-contrib`. From the [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) page, you have two choices:

> 1. Copy `ant-contrib-0.3.jar` to the lib directory of your Ant
>      installation. If you want to use one of the tasks in your own project,
>      add the line `<taskdef
>      resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>` to your build
>      file.
> 2. Keep `ant-contrib-0.3.jar` in a separate location. You now have to
>      tell Ant explicitly where to find it (say in `/usr/share/java/lib`):
>
>    `<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">`
>         `<classpath>`
>           `<pathelement
>      location="/usr/share/java/lib/ant-contrib-0.3.jar"/>`
>         `</classpath>`
>       `</taskdef>`

Comment: when using Ant > version 1.5 you should use : <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/> because the antcontrib.properties file provides only the tasks compatible with Ant before version 1.6, so f.e. the for task is missing in the antcontrib.properties file, see : http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/index.html Installation, section 3.

Answer (score 3):

I leave it here.
I've experienced the similar error some time ago while I tried to compile my python project in *IntelliJ IDEA*. In my case it was required to specify custom Ant (check `Use custom Ant` radio button) instead of the default one. After I made those updates everything worked fine. Please find the screenshot below.
[image]

That worked for me, hope it'll be helpful.